# Mandrill is not replace merge tag content in html template

Tags: php, api, mandrill

```
     Mandrill API Logs  -- 

"subject": "Valentine’s Day special offer. Additional 10% off* on select categories! View exclusive online offer",
        "from_email": "habits@zip.in",
        "from_name": "zipp",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "xyza_123@gmail.com",
                "name": "venk",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ],
        "merge": true,
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "xyza_123@gmail.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "UNSUB",
                        "content": "http://zyr.com/unsubscribe/GYT786HHG"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "FirstName",
                        "content": "venk"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

    "async": false,
    "ip_pool": null,
    "send_at": null,
```

And when I click on the unsubscriber link in the template, it takes me to the url `http://*|unsub|*`. Mandrill is not replacing *|UNSUB|* with `http://zyr.com/unsubscribe/GYT&786HHG`. Please help me . I spent a lot of time on it, but am unable to solve it

```
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:9px; padding-right: 18px; padding-bottom: 9px; padding-left: 18px;">

                            You can&nbsp;<a href="*|UNSUB|*" target="_blank">unsubscribe</a><br>
<br>
&nbsp;
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to pass in UNSUB as a merge variable. [Mandrill takes care of all of that for you](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582947-About-Unsubscribes). UNSUB is a reserved merge tag too, which is why it's not being replaced with the value you pass in your API call.

So in your API call, remove the merge var altogether:

```
 {
                    "name": "UNSUB",
                    "content": "http://zyr.com/unsubscribe/GYT786HHG"
                },
```

And in your HTML template, use this instead:

```
You can&nbsp;<a href="*|UNSUB:http://zyr.com/unsubscribe/GYT786HHG|*" target="_blank">unsubscribe</a><br>
```

Comment: Hi @terrorbox. for every user i am generating a unique unsubscribe url and appending it to merge variable.. i can't use it in html template. it is a dynamic url ..

Comment: @user3442132 In that case, you won't be able to use the Mandrill UNSUB merge tag since it's reserved (the Mandrill unsub merge tag also creates a per-recipient link for tracking purposes, so it's also dynamic). Instead, you could use a merge tag like "*|MYUNSUB|*".

Comment: i have tried including *|MYUNSUB|* but it didn't work. when i click on the link it takes me to http://*|myunsub|*/ on bowser.. But when i include it on html <span> *|MYUNSUB|* </span> mandrill is replacing it with dynamic url.. but not on the anchor tag href link